# How can I make multiple @wraps smaller?

Tags: python, functools

I don't really know enough (yet) about python to figure this out myself, so that's why  I wanted to try here. Is there any way to make these almost identical @wraps functions take up less space? I've got 5 of these in total, and 100 lines for 5x the same thing sounds like a  waste. I originally found this on some website, but I can't seem to find it anymore.

The functions:

```
def a_required(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def decorated_view(*args, **kwargs):
        if request.method in EXEMPT_METHODS:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        elif current_app.config.get('LOGIN_DISABLED'):
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        elif not current_user.is_authenticated or not current_user["Keys"]["A"]:
            return current_app.login_manager.unauthorized()
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_view

def b_required(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def decorated_view(*args, **kwargs):
        if request.method in EXEMPT_METHODS:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        elif current_app.config.get('LOGIN_DISABLED'):
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        elif not current_user.is_authenticated or not current_user["Keys"]["B"]:
            return current_app.login_manager.unauthorized()
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_view
```

This is for a Flask website, with pages that would only be accesible to users with the right rights.

Comment: You can write a "higher order" function that returns such a decorator function, but with the key (a, b,...) in question as a parameter to the outer function.

Comment: Could you show an example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write a function that returns a decorator, and call it like so:

```py
def required(req):
    def wrapper(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def decorated_view(*args, **kwargs):
            # put your decorated_view code here
            #  swapping out the hard coded `current_user["Keys"]["B"]`
            #  for `current_user["Keys"][req]`

            print("executing decorator with", req)
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return decorated_view
    return wrapper

@required("B")
def foo():
    print("inside foo function")
    
@required("A")
def bar():
    print("inside bar function")
```

Then executing these functions looks like:

```py
>>> foo()
executing decorator with B
inside foo function

>>> bar()
executing decorator with A
inside bar function
```

The function `required` returns a dynamic decorator that changes its behavior depending on the value `req` we pass to it. This way, the `decorated_view` function can access the appropriate value of `req` depending on how we invoked `required(...)`.

Comment: The `nonlocal` statement is not required here, since you're not writing to  `req`.

Comment: good point, I've removed it from the snippet.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
def required(req):
    def wrapper(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def decorated_view(*args, **kwargs):
            if not current_user.is_authenticated or not current_user["Keys"][req]:
                return current_app.login_manager.unauthorized()
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return decorated_view
    return wrapper
    
@required("A")
def method1():
    pass
    
@required("B")
def method2():
    pass
```